# How to conditionally show some components in a custom Dialog?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I need to create a custom dialog, so I'm doing so as follows:

```
    private void ShowSetOptions(Activity context, UserOptions userOptions)
    {
        var dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.view_set_unset_buttons);
    }
```

The layout

```
view_set_unset_buttons
```

is basically a list of buttons which the user can press.

The trouble is, depending on the the value of `userOptions`, I don't want to show all the buttons in `view_set_unset_buttons`.

Is there a way for me to apply logic to the creation of `view_set_unset_buttons` so that I can hide some of the buttons?

**SOLUTION:**

The solution is to implement my own Dialog box, as outlined in this answer: [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android/13342157#13342157)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your own `Dialog` with a custom layout, then define the layout programmatically before showing the dialog. That would be the best practice. Cheers.

Comment: This is what I needed to do. I used the following as a guideline for implementing the Dialog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android/13342157#13342157

Answer (score 0):

From my experience resources are compiled statically, so i don't think they are modifiable once you run the program. Why don't you add the buttons programatically? Instead of specifying in your R file, why don't you create a `ListView` object dynamically and add it to the dialog? You can use `setAdapter` function to add the dynamic data you need.